# Liboauth request is failing

Tags: c++, oauth

I am trying with  program code from 
http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/tests_2oauthexample_8c-example.html

but every time I am getting

```
"HTTP request for an oauth request-token failed.\n"
```

I am behind proxy .

what I need to edit to make it work behind proxy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the code of lib file outh_http.c

to include proxy details in curl request.